# More threads imply more context switching? Is this true for the Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, operating-system, scheduling

There seems to be a widely spread idea that more threads imply more context switching but it just so happens that I'm not very sold to that idea -- at least it doesn't seem immediately obvious to me why would that be.

As my understanding goes, we have CPUs that are at any given moment assigned a bunch of threads to run -- their run-queues. In the modern Linux kernel, those run-queues consist actually in Red-Black-Trees, so for each run task will impose on that tree operations on the order of `O(lg n)`. From this perspective it seems that if we have a system with lots of threads running around, on average the `n` of this `O(lg n)` will also increase -- but this is not really increasing the context switching count, just increasing the cost of each context switch.

From all other perspectives I don't think that having more or less threads will increase the context switching. It may increase the memory used (at least one user-space and one kernel-space stacks, plus maybe thread or at least cpu-local memory pools) but not the number of context switches.

Let's imagine that I have a program with an embarrassingly parallel workload that runs for hours, with plenty of ram to go around. What would be the difference between having, let's say, 8 entirely CPU-bound threads (in a 8 core machine) or  64? The only reason I could see a difference would be if the Linux scheduler algorithm would assign smaller slices (up to a point, of course) as the number of threads in its run-queue increases?

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Doesn’t scheduler give a chance to each thread to be waken up? Thus, the frequency of switching is increasing. Also, there is a FUTEX approach to reduce cost of the switch.

Comment: @0andriy: I don't understand what you mean. If the processor load is, let's say, 100%, it will roughly mean that on each millisecond a context switch is going to happen. As long as the calculations are entirely CPU-bound, the number of threads then should be irrelevant.

Comment: @devouredelysium yes, you are sorta correct.  If the number of CPU-intensive  READY threads exceeds the number of cores, and a periodic timer causes a scheduler run, then somewhere between one and [number of cores] cores will be assigned a different thread to run. If the number of READY threads is greater than twice the number of cores, it does not matter how many more ready threads might exist - only [number of cores] context changes can happen.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right.  Whether you have N-ready threads per cpu or (N+1), there will be the same number of context switches.  Your embarrassingly parallel app would run fastest with 1 thread per cpu.

The length of the runq doesn't have a significant impact upon context switch overhead; more cpu caches, page table caches and the like being re-assigned.   Typical workloads are neither embarrassingly parallel nor ready-only; and it especially in areas like contention on condvars where the number of threads can rear its ugly head.   If you google about the golang scheduler, there was a brilliant talk about it at GopherCon 2018.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the scheduler is awful (e.g. a round-robin thing with no thread priorities); and that you have 10 CPUs and an embarrassingly parallel load (as a single process) where its threads never block, and nothing else wanting the CPUs.

This is simple to reason about - with less than 10 threads you will have idle CPUs (which will hurt performance) and no thread switches. With 10 threads you will have no idle CPUs and no thread switches (which is ideal). With more than 10 threads you will start to have thread switches (which will also hurt performance, not just because of the cost of the thread switches themselves, but also because of increased lock contention, less efficient use of caches, etc). With 20 or more threads all CPUs will be doing thread switches as often as "time slice length" tells them to (and more threads just increases the secondary costs, like lock contention and cache efficiency, without increasing the number of thread switches).

However, it's extremely rare to have one embarrassingly parallel load (as a single process) that never blocks. Far more likely is 100 processes that aren't embarrassingly parallel, each doing very different work with different threads (at different priorities, with different latency constraints) that do block (wait for IO or time or...) and often spend most of their time blocked. In this case, if threads spend (e.g.) an average of 95% of the time blocked then you can probably have about 200 threads on 10 CPUs, and balance "risk of CPU idle" against "risk of thread switch".

However, the real world doesn't work like that either - the real world has surges. Maybe when it's Saturday evening in USA your game server gets pounded for 6+ hours. Maybe at 9:00 AM on Monday morning your cooperate email server gets flooded by all employees at the same time. Maybe you have a "build server" that spends 2 hours processing C++ templates at 4:00 PM each day. It's these surges that matter most - you can't look at the average (including all the time nobody cares about) and use that average for planning purposes.

More specifically; (outside of niches, like HPC where the worst scheduler in the world is perfectly fine) a "theoretically ideal situation that never changes" is an over-simplified fantasy, and reality is that nothing is constant and nothing can be predicted accurately in advance. What you really want is a semi-intelligent adaptive system that is designed to make the best decisions under constantly changing conditions, which can rely on useful (not "guessed wrong maybe") information as the basis of its decisions (and not just latency and throughput for threads, but things like CPU temperatures and UPS battery state and future load that can be predicted). Sadly, the scheduler in Linux is awful; so the only thing you can really do is assume that (unless you're working with a theoretically ideal situation that never changes, where the worst scheduler in the world is fine) there's no point caring because there's no way to prevent the scheduler from ruining everything anyway.